# Struct in for loop initializer

Tags: go, struct, composite-literals

Any idea why this struct expression in for loop initializer makes syntax error in compile-time? Pointer to struct works fine in this case but ofc I need local variable like bellow. Thanks for advices!

```
type Request struct {
    id   int
    line []byte
    err  error
}

go func() {
    for r := Request{}; r.err == nil; r.id++ {
        r.line, r.err = input.ReadSlice(0x0a)
        channel <- r
    }
}()
```

Comment: This gave me a big 'wtf' moment today. First time I've seen this error in years of Go.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simplifying you code:

```
for r := Request{}; r.err == nil; r.id++ {
    r.line, r.err = input.ReadSlice(0x0a)
    channel <- r
}
```

Gives compile time error:

> expected boolean or range expression, found simple statement (missing parentheses around composite literal?) (and 1 more errors)

This construct is ambiguous to parse. The opening brace `'{'` is not obvious whether it is part of a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) or the opening brace of the `for` statement itself (the `for` [block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Block)).

You can make it obvious by using parentheses around the composite literal (as the error suggests):

```
for r := (Request{}); r.err == nil; r.id++ {
    r.line, r.err = input.ReadSlice(0x0a)
    channel <- r
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like a Gosublime has different error output..without these suggestions..

Comment: @bigless, (sorry to excavate an old thread but) the output of the compiler may depend on its version: the exact wording of the error messages produced by the toolchain is not covered by the [Go (v1) compatibility guarantees](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat), so it's quite possible that icza merely has a version of Go installed different from that of yours.

Comment: `go build` doesn't produce that kind of output indeed but `go vet` does. Checked with `go1.17.5`.