# How do I check the equality of three values elegantly?

Tags: go, syntax, equality, readability, convention

Say I have values `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to find out if they are equal. If I do

```
if a == b == c{...}
```

Then I get a compile error

```
invalid operation: a == b == c (mismatched types bool and TypeOfABandC)
```

This is pretty obvious, because this parses to:

```
(a == b) == c
```

And `(a == b)` is a bool.

Of course I can do:

```
if a == b && a == c {...}
```

However, this isn't very nice looking and feels confusing. Is there another way?

Comment: You could make a static class that accepts var args and returns a boolean.

Comment: Whats confusing about the last example? It's explicitly what's going on, and you still can elide the transitive comparison of `b == c`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**A note beforehand:**

Your last proposed solution *is* the shortest, clearest and most efficient way to compare if 3 values are equal:

```
if a == b && a == c {
    fmt.Println("Clearest: all 3 are equal")
}
```

or alternatively (to your liking):

```
if a == b && b == c {
    fmt.Println("Clearest: all 3 are equal")
}
```

The rest of this answer (what follows) is just toying with the language specification and the language's capabilities, presenting what I find fun and creative. They do not attempt to provide a superior solution.

---

Try all the examples below on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nzJFJ5Yfon). The examples build on the terms and the result of the comparisons which are defined in [Spec: Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

General note: in the examples below I used the type `interface{}` which will work whatever type your values have (`a`, `b` and `c`), but if you know they are of type `int` for example, you can use that specific type too (which would improve efficiency and shorten the length of the examples).

#### With a `map` as a set

```
if len(map[interface{}]int{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}) == 1 {
    fmt.Println("Map set: all 3 are equal")
}
```

Effectively we put all comparable values into a `map` as keys, and if all are equal, there will be only 1 pair in the map, so the "length" of the map will be 1. The value type of the map doesn't play any role here, it could be anything. I used `int` because this results in the shortest [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) (that defines the `map` value).

This solution is flexible as you can use any number of values to test if all are equal, not just 3.

#### With arrays

Arrays are comparable (unlike slices):

```
if [2]interface{}{a, b} == [2]interface{}{b, c} {
    fmt.Println("Arrays: all 3 are equal")
}
```

The result of the array comparison will be `true` if `a == b` and `b == c` (if the corresponding elements are equal).

Note that you can apply this method on any number of values as well. It would look like this for 5 values:

```
if [4]interface{}{a, b, c, d} == [4]interface{}{b, c, d, e} {
    fmt.Println("Arrays: all 5 are equal")
}
```

#### With a tricky `map`

```
if map[interface{}]bool{a: b == c}[b] {
    fmt.Println("Tricky map: all 3 are equal")
}
```

This composite literal will assign the comparision result of `b == c` to the key `a`. And we ask the value associated with the key `b`. If `a == b`, the result of the indexing expression will be the result of `b == c`, that is, whether all 3 values are equal. If `a != b`, then the zero value of the value type will be the result, which is `false` in case of `bool`, properly telling that all 3 values are not equal.

#### With anonymous `struct`s

`struct` values are also comparable, so:

```
if struct{ a, b interface{} }{a, b} == struct{ a, b interface{} }{b, c} {
    fmt.Println("Anon structs: all 3 are equal")
}
```

#### With (named) `struct`s

If we define a simple `struct` beforehand:

```
type P struct{ a, b interface{} }
```

Comparison will be much more compact:

```
if (P{a, b} == P{b, c}) {
    fmt.Println("Structs: all 3 are equal")
}
```

(Note that the expression of the `if` statement must be put in parenthesis to avoid [parsing ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120724/struct-in-for-loop-initializer) - else it's a compile time error!)

#### With slices

Slices are not comparable, so we will need to borrow some help from [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual):

```
if reflect.DeepEqual([]interface{}{a, b}, []interface{}{b, c}) {
    fmt.Println("Slices: all 3 are equal")
}
```

#### With a helper function

```
func AllEquals(v ...interface{}) bool {
    if len(v) > 1 {
        a := v[0]
        for _, s := range v {
            if a != s {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And using it:

```
if AllEquals(a, b, c) {
    fmt.Println("Helper function: all 3 are equal")
}
```

This solution is also flexible, you can call `AllEquals()` with any number of values.

Note that we can make the `AllEquals()` function more compact if we're also willing to call `reflect.DeepEqual()` here:

```
func AllEquals2(v ...interface{}) bool {
    if len(v) < 2 {
        return true
    }
    return reflect.DeepEqual(v[:len(v)-1], v[1:])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll be sticking with a == b && b == c. However, your tricky map is pretty cleaver ;)