# GoLang, how to write a multi-line statement if condtion

Tags: if-statement, go, comparison

I want to match bellow `a` value with `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` at once instead of writing multiple times like this.

My values are:

```
a = 11
b = 22
c = 33
d = 44
e = 55
f = 66

if a != b && a != c && a != d && a != e && a != f{
    // Do something
} else{
    // Do something else
}
```

Is actual working code method I have.

But I want to write it like

```
if a != b or c or d or e or f {print text}
```

`a` value should be used once in if statement. Is there is any easy method?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang: How do I check the equality of three values elegantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884152/golang-how-do-i-check-the-equality-of-three-values-elegantly/37889261#37889261)

Answer (score 8):

Actually you may implement this with a single `switch` statement:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f := 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

switch a {
case b, c, d, e, f:
    fmt.Println("'a' matches another!")
default:
    fmt.Println("'a' matches none")
}
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fWQA6GUnMHz)):

```
'a' matches none
```

Using `switch` is the cleanest and fastest solution.

Another solution could be to list the values you want `a` to compare to, and use a `for` loop to range over them and do the comparison:

This is how it could look like:

```
match := false
for _, v := range []int{b, c, d, e, f} {
    if a == v {
        fmt.Println("'a' matches another!")
        match = true
        break
    }
}
if !match {
    fmt.Println("'a' matches none")
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/elcizT2YZWQ). Although this is more verbose and less efficient, this has the advantage that the values to compare to can be *dynamic*, e.g. decided at runtime, while the `switch` solution must be decided at compile time.

Also check related question: [How do I check the equality of three values elegantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884152/golang-how-do-i-check-the-equality-of-three-values-elegantly/37889261#37889261)

Comment: its very helpful,

Comment: in this can we use simple method for comparing multiple values like
a or b maches
c, d, e, f

switch a, b {
case c, d, e, f:
    fmt.Println("'a or b' matches another!")
default:
    fmt.Println("'a or b' matches none")
}

Comment: Incidentally, the switch version can also be used as a compact method of checking an interface variable against a list of _types_.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/xjGQ-HNyjy3

Answer (score 1):

I would use `switch` statement

```
a := 11
b := 22
c := 33
d := 44
e := 55
f := 66
switch a {
case b, c, d, e, f:
default:
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```