# What does initializing a Go struct in parentheses do?

Tags: go, struct, composite-literals

Normally, I will initialize a struct like:

```
item1 := Item{1, "Foo"}
```

However, I've recently seen code initializing with parens:

```
item2 := (Item{2, "Bar"})
```

`reflect` returns the same `Item` name.

What does initializing in parentheses do and when is it preferred?

Here's some Go code to try this out:

- Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_gsaruS_DVi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does nothing special, those 2 lines are identical.

However, when you want to use that in an `if` statement for example, the parentheses will be required, else you get a compile time error:

```
if i := Item{3, "a"}; i.Id == 3 {
}
```

Results in:

> expected boolean expression, found simple statement (missing parentheses around composite literal?) (and 1 more errors)

This is because a parsing ambiguity arises: it's not obvious if the opening brace would be part of the composite literal or the body of the `if` statement.

Using parentheses will make it unambiguous for the compiler, so this works:

```
if i := (Item{3, "a"}); i.Id == 3 {
}
```

For details, see: [Struct in for loop initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120724/struct-in-for-loop-initializer/35120825#35120825)